# deleting bytes from an ostringstream

Tags: c++

how do i delete the first n bytes of an ostringstream?

I basically have to see howmany bytes went over a socket and if it did not go through fully...i have to delete whatever went through

Comment: Just a note given your other socket-related questions.  You should make sure you understand that TCP is a byte-stream protocol, and what that means for your application logic.  You need the receiving side to loop when it reads less data than expected, piecing together complete messages if necessary: you can not ask read to return the number of bytes in some larger message you happened to pass to a single send call and expect it to arrive in one piece on the receiving side.  Only when your receiving side returns 0 (while blocking) or -1 should you give up on your message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do what you said : remove the first n bytes ?

```
ostr.str(ostr.str().substr(n))
```